# Can't import const enums in webpack with babel project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babel-loader

I am working on a react project which was built using create-react-app and later we ejected and modified the webpack config a lot. Right now I am having a hard time importing `const enums` from external libraries. I don't have control over that external package. It has the const enums defined in its `d.ts` files.

I have tried with `babel-plugin-use-const-enum` babel plugin and preset. It doesn't help me either.

**My webpack config:**

```
.....
.....
{
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  include: [paths.appSrc],
  loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
  options: {
    customize: require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides"),
    plugins: [
        [require.resolve("babel-plugin-const-enum"), { transform: "constObject" }],
        [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"), { isTSX: true, optimizeConstEnums: true }],
        [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx")],
        [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"), { loose: true }],
        [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator")],
        [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"), { isTSX: true }],
        [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions")],
        [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"), { loose: true }],
        [
          require.resolve("babel-plugin-named-asset-import"),
          {
            loaderMap: {
              svg: {
                ReactComponent: "@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
    ],
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
  },
},
.....
.....
```

**My tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./typings", "node_modules/@types"],
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "exclude": ["dist/**/*"],
}
```

The problem is that the build is successful but I am facing the runtime issue with all the const enums import like below

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '<ConstEnumName>')`.

**Package versions:**

```
"@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
"babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
"typescript": "^3.9.7",
"webpack": "^4.44.2",
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing a reproducible repo?

Comment: Is that external package an open-source project? Perhaps you could share its name. I want to make a reproduction of the issue and try a workaround I have in mind. The best would be to try it with the actual package.

Comment: No it's not an open source project. ts-loader fixed my issue. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8741#issuecomment-629779409), where the plugin's creator is involved, babel does not transpile `.d.ts` files, making it impossible to get enums from there. The only option seems to be [migrating](https://evanlouie.github.io/posts/typescript-babel-preset-typescript-ts-loader) your config to use `ts-loader` and [include](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/706) the `.d.ts` files that have the enum declarations

**tsconfig**

```
{
  ...
  "exclude": ["dist/**/*"],
  "include": ["node_modules/[external_library]/**/*.d.ts"],
}
```